# Is it possible to implement Agora Video Call in flutter web and flutter app?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, agora.io, flutter-android

I was wondering if it is possible to make a video call between a flutter web app and flutter mobile application. In pub dev's agora_rtc_engine 4.0.6, it only says there, "Android and IOS supported". So I guess web is not yet supported?

If not, is there any alternative solution that I could use for my project to achieve this feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank [meherdeep thakur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13055253/meherdeep-thakur) for his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69091686/1260976).

Based on this, I implemented the web version of my Flutter project.

1. Change the version of [agora_rtc_engine](https://pub.dev/packages/agora_rtc_engine/versions/4.1.0-alpha.2) in `pubspec.yaml`:

   ```
   agora_rtc_engine: ^4.1.0-alpha.2
   ```
2. Download the [AgoraRtcWrapper.bundle.js](https://github.com/AgoraIO/Agora-Flutter-SDK/blob/dev/flutter2/example/web/AgoraRtcWrapper.bundle.js) file: [Raw Link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AgoraIO/Agora-Flutter-SDK/dev/flutter2/example/web/AgoraRtcWrapper.bundle.js)
3. Import the `AgoraRtcWrapper.bundle.js` file into the project.

   > `Project Root`/web/AgoraRtcWrapper.bundle.js
4. Add the file to `Project Root`/web/index.html

   ```
   <script src="AgoraRtcWrapper.bundle.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
   ```

Comment: This works perfectly. Amazing thanks!

Comment: This was the last feature I implemented in my project and it works perfectly as well. I was able to achieve a video call between web-to-mobile platform. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Agora Flutter SDK provides web support but it is currently available as a prerelease. To use it in your application you can use the v[4.1.0-alpha.2](https://pub.dev/packages/agora_rtc_engine/versions/4.1.0-alpha.2)

Comment: Thanks for the info! Anyway, do u have any idea when they are going to officially release their web support?

Answer (score -1):

Yes Defiantly add agora video call SDK with flutter web and flutter app.
for this you can read documentation:
visit https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/start_call_flutter?platform=Flutter

and This Plugin will all you to use Agora video call functionality in your application: visit https://pub.dev/packages/agora_rtc_engine

Comment: What do you mean? @emmy-chwan